# Is this right to say ' it feels like so cozy?'

Tags: grammaticality

Actually once my friend was trying on some dresses and for one dress she used this sentence. Is this correct grammatically?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you live in California, the "like" is extraneous.  *"It feels so cozy"* is natural, where the "so" means "very".

In many parts of California (and possibly elsewhere), the local vernacular is to use "like" as a kind of *punctuation*.  It doesn't usually add any *meaning* to the sentence, but it can add emphasis.

Some examples:

> I told her that she was, like, being really stubborn.
>
> That dress, like, looks so good on you!
>
> Like, I wanted to go, but I didn't *really* want to go.

I wouldn't recommend using this, though.  It's just information so you can recognize the vernacular if you hear it.

Comment: You wouldn't, like, recommend it? :)

Comment: Nah dude.  Totally bogus!

Comment: I will add that having grown up in California, extraneous likes creep into my diction if I don't pay attention. Doesn't matter how much education you've had, you never outgrow it.

Comment: Look, sometimes even highly educated people use like. It's no big deal unless every other word is like.

Answer (score 1):

Only if *like* is an interjection, and it should be written this way to clarify:

> it feels, like, so cozy

When X is *like* Y, that means means X shares qualities with Y.  The implication in expressions using this interjection is the speaker cannot find the correct word, but is offering the first thing that comes to their mind or a simpler word to try to express what they want.

If *like* is not being used in this manner, it doesn't work.  In *like X*, X must be a noun, and while you can say *so like X* you can't say *like so X* (though *like so much X* or *like so many X* is OK).

Answer (score 0):

If the dress was warm, then perhaps cozy might be used. As the two (so far) answers have pointed out, 'like' is an affectation and completely unnecessary in this sentence.

This dress is (nice and) warm.

This dress is comfortable.

This robe/dressing gown is cozy because of the fabric.